# How to comapare jquery date stored in html5 local storage is already past 12 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using html5 local storage to store date as following:

```
var object = {value: "value", timestamp: new Date().getTime()}
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(object));
var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key")),
dateString = object.timestamp,
now = new Date().getTime().toString();
compareTime(dateString, now);
alert(datestring - now);   //tried this but it always alerts 0.
```

Now I want to know how to make a function that can check if time stored in localstorage is already past 12 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You will know your code was correct, if you use timeout for get now.

```
var object = {value: "value", timestamp: new Date().getTime()}
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(object));
var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key")),
    dateString = object.timestamp;
setTimeout(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime().toString();
    alert(dateString - now);
}, 1000);
```